# Functions in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am quite new to nginx, I have a nginx conf script that has following template, **example1** and **example2** has the same content, i want to put those content in a function (same concept like methods in programming), and pass parameters inside to reduce duplication, is it possible to do so? I searched for a long time but didn't see an example that do similar stuff.

```
server {
   server_name test.com

  location ^~ /example1/ {
      proxy_pass http://<some-ip>/example1/;
      proxy_set_header blah

  }

  location ^~ /example2/ {
      proxy_pass http://<some-ip>/example2/;
      proxy_set_header blah

  }

}
```

Comment: The ngnix config file is neither a script nor a programming language. There are no "functions".

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thanks for the quick reply, so i assume i have to stuck with the duplication right?

Comment: There are no functions, but certain identical statements can be inherited or included. See [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) and [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directives.

Comment: I don't see why this question garnered downvotes. Defining functions or macros in a config file is a perfectly sensible thing to want to do, and the fact that it isn't possible is a deficiency of Nginx, in my view; not all directives that you'll need to share between blocks can be inherited from a higher context, so frequently you're forced into duplicating config or going for some more complicated solution like using `include` or generating your `nginx.conf` with a separate templating language. The fact that the answer is "this isn't possible" doesn't make the question bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like comments mentioned, there are no functions in nginx. For those, you would need a configuration management system.

However, to combine these two blocks, you can use regex capture:

```
location ~ ^/(example1|example2/)$ {
    proxy_pass http://some.ip/$1;
    ... rest of configuration directives ...
}
```

One can expand the regular expression to match files under those paths, for example:

```
location ~ ^/(example1|example2/)(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://some.ip/$1$2;
    ... rest of configuration directives ...
}
```

matches all files after those paths in URLs and adds them to `proxy_pass`.

Comment: From the first example, the $1 in `proxy_pass http://some.ip/$1;`  will be either example1 or example2, but what about the $2 regex capture `in proxy_pass http://some.ip/$1$2;` ?

Comment: It is the contents of the second regex capture group, that is `(.+)`, which in this case is the rest of the normalized request URI.